# Sql requires scalar to be declared

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following sql (Sql Server 2016) generates an error:

```
INSERT INTO Requests (EntryDate,Status, AccountID)
VALUES (@EntryDate,@Status,@accountID)"; 
        try
        { 
            DatabaseConnection.Execute(sql,
    new
    {             
        DateTime.Now,
        Status = (int)Status.New, '''an enum
        accountID,             
    }, this.Transaction);
```

This generates the error:

```
 Must declare scalar variable @EntryDate.
```

If I replace @EntryDate with getdate(), this runs OK. Even though it seems that getdate() is not used. Why this one value?

Comment: Could you please show the part of your code where you DECLARE your variables and where you set them?

Comment: It's right in the error message--@EntryDate isn't declared anywhere.  When you use a variable, you have to declare it.  YU no declare it?

Comment: @JeroenMostert: This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Why is "@EntryDate" different from "@Status" or "@accountID"? That's my question.

Comment: Your code seems to be an incomplete mish-mash of SQL and (C#?). Please at least give us a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@EntryDate` is a parameter of your command. You must supply it as such, even if the value is unused, otherwise SQL Server will look for a variable named `@EntryDate` (which likewise doesn't exist).

If you write `new { DateTime.Now, ... }` you are passing an anonymous object with a property named `Now`, which can't be mapped to the actual parameter. Change `DateTime.Now` to `EntryDate = DateTime.Now` so the name matches up. The question doesn't specify which object-relational mapper you are using (Dapper?) but they will all need to pass named parameters somehow.